# Backbone.js Loss of focus during Ctrl+s event

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have the following issue: I'm building a backbone application and when I attempt to save some text with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>, the app `textarea` loses the focus and some strange behavior follows,

```
onTextareaKeyDown: function(evt) {
      var key = evt.keyCode;     
      if(evt.ctrlKey)
      {
        switch(key){       
          case 83: 
            evt.preventDefault();   
            this.saveText();
          break;
        }
      }          
    },
```

**Edit:** The strange behavior, yes. Mainly, I noticed that when I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> inside it loses the focus on the textarea, and when I bring back the focus, it loses focus for every a key pressed after that.

Comment: What is that strange behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have model `change` events causing your view to rerender? My guess is the DOM is being changed in response to model events.

Comment: Thank you very much, was precisely that, it was re-rendering every time. I should wait to post here, looks so obvious now.. :/

Answer (score 0):

you try with also this code.

```
onTextareaKeyDown: function(evt) {
      var key = evt.keyCode;     
      if (key == 83 && evt.ctrlKey){
          evt.preventDefault();   
          this.saveText();
      } 
},
```

Example demo: http://jsfiddle.net/29sVC/